# Why I have error while I get url by Python script, but my browser open the same url easy?

Tags: python, http, https, http-status-code-503

I try to collect transactions data from miningpoolhub.com. There is a python script:

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing

    def query_url(url):
        try:
            with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
                if is_good_response(resp):
                    return resp.content
                else:
                    return None
```

The url looks like 'https://ethereum.miningpoolhub.com/index.php?page=account&action=transactions&start=30'
and, resp is always Response 503.
I am logged into MPH.com in my Chrome browser, and the same url opens successfull. 
What is my mistake?
May be the reason be in Cloudflare DDOS protection?

Comment: Either it's a genuine error or the server detected that you're trying to connect programmatically and throws the error back at you. You may be able to set `headers` to get around it but you haven't shown much detail

Comment: You are *logged in* in Chrome.

Comment: There is no details, cause there is not any code runs before this. I am not familiar with HTTP and imported libraries, but I will look toward this direction.

Comment: Are you sure? If I not logged in in Chrome, it shows me log in page, but not 503 error.